# Which final velocity formula is to be used here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-fields

[image]

In this question, acceleration is obviously $a=eE/m$. So, I used the final velocity formula as $V_y^2-u^2=2as$, where $u=0$ is the initial speed in the $y$ direction and $s$ is the distance travelled in the $y$ direction,
therefore $V_y=(2eEs/m)^{1/2}$
But my book used the formula:

[image]

They used $t$ from uniform $x$ motion and got a different value for $V_y$.
How do I know which formula to use?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: aaravm, note that this is actually a projectile motion problem, where the electron is falling up, not down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both formulae are correct, however $s$ in your case is not the same as $\ell$. In this case, $s$ will be the vertical distance the particle travels, which you don't know in this question. Also $u$ should really be $u_y$, because the suvat equations work independently in each direction. You *do* however know lots of things about the $x$-direction, such as how long it takes it cross the 1m plate horizontally.  This is why you should use $v_y=a_yt$, since $t$ is the same in both directions.

Comment: You could equate your expression for $v_y$ and theirs to find an expression for $s$, but that's not what the question wants.

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers are correct at one spot. In your approach $s$ is taken as the displacement in the $y$ direction, but the question asks for an answer in terms of $l$. So we use the formula stated in your image. Hope it helps.☺